# BIP-330 test cases

Tags: p2p, bip

Are there any test cases for BIP-330 "Transaction announcements reconciliation"? More specifically, I need some test cases for the serialization/deserialization of the new p2p messages, something like a byte-array of the data and what it should look like after parsed. I couldn't find it in the BIP or in the PRs.